# How to use Write-behind with foreign keys in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, jdbc, ignite

I am experiencing an issue while trying to use write-behind on caches connected to tables which have foreign key constraints between them. Seemingly the write-behind mechanism is not executing the updates/inserts in a deterministic order, but rather is trying to push all the collected changes per each cache consecutively in some unknown order. But as we have foreign keys in the tables, the order of the operation matters, so parent objects should be inserted/updated first, and children only after that (otherwise foreign key violations are thrown from the DB).

It seems that the current implementation is trying to workaround this problem on a trial-and-error basis (`org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore:888`), which means that it will periodically retry to flush the changes again and again for the caches in case of which a constraint violation occured. So the "child" cache will periodically retry to flush, until the "parent" cache gets flushed first. This ultimately will result in getting the data into the DB, but it also means a lot of unsuccessful tries in case of complex hierarchical tables, until the correct order is "found". This results in poor performance and unnecessary shelling of the DB.

Do you have any suggestions on how could I circumvent this issue?

(Initially I were trying with write-through, but it resulted in VERY poor performance, because the `CacheAbstractJdbcStore` is seemingly opening a new prepared statement for each insert/update operation.)

Answer (score 4):

With write-behind the order of store updates is undefined because each node writes independently and asynchronously. If you have foreign key constraints, you should use write-through.

As for write-through performance, `CacheAbstractJdbcStore` operates with a configurable `DataSource`, so it depend on its implementation whether it opens a new connection each time or not. If you use some pooled version, this will not happen.